# Closure properties of languages

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, context-free, closure-properties

> Let $P$ be a regular language and $Q$ be a context-free language such
>   that $Q \subseteq P$(For example, let $P =  a^*b^*$ and $Q = \{ a^nb^n | n \ge 0\}$). Then which of the following is always regular?
>
> 1. $P \cap Q$
> 2. $P - Q$
> 3. $\Sigma^* - Q$
> 4. $\Sigma^* - P$

**Option 1** 
$P \cap Q = Q$ as $P \subseteq Q$. Thus $P \cap Q$ is context-free.

**Option 2** 
I was not able to generally reason here. I used the example mentioned in the question.
Let  $P =  a^*b^* $ and $Q = \{ a^nb^n | n \ge 0\}$. 
$P - Q = \{a^nb^m | n \neq m\}$ which is not regular but only context-free.

**Option - 3**
Let $\Sigma = \{ a, b\}$ and $Q = \{ a^nb^n | n \ge 0\}$. 
Again $\Sigma^* - Q =  \{a^nb^m | n \neq m\} $ which is not regular but only  context-free.

Thus, the 4th option must be right, $\Sigma^* - P$ is regular. I am however unable to understand this result intuitively. Could somebody explain?

Comment: Note $\Sigma^* - Q$ also contains strings not in $a^*b^*$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it on further thought. It is trivial. $\Sigma^* - P$ is $P'$, the complement of P and this is regular. I was unnecessarily concentrating on how $Q \subseteq P$ would play a role. It doesn't actually.

Comment: That's right, $\Sigma^{*} - P$ will always be regular because $P$ is regular and the regular languages are closed under complement.